# List<string> items disappearring in c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a simple List wrapper class:

```
class ExtensionList
{
    public List<string> Extensions;

    public ExtensionList()
    {
        Extensions = new List<string>();
    }

    public void push(params string[] ext)
    {
        // Add the * extension if "ALL__" is pushed.
        if (ext.Contains("ALL__"))
        {
            Extensions = new List<string>();
            Extensions.Add("*");
            return;
        }

        // Don't add duplicate if pushed extension is already in list.
        if (Extensions.Intersect(ext).Any())
            return;

        Extensions.AddRange(ext);
    }
}
```

and a loop that instantiates 'Rec's, each of which has one of the above list objects.

```
public bool readAppConfig(string appConfigPath)
    {
        Recs = new Dictionary<string, List<Rec>>()
        {
            {"Headers",    new List<Rec>()},
            {"Ignores",    new List<Rec>()},
            {"Exceptions", new List<Rec>()}
        };

        foreach (string sectionName in Recs.Keys)
        {
            var recSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName) as NameValueCollection;
            foreach (string key in recSection.AllKeys)
            {
                Rec r = new Rec();
                r.strMatch = key;
                r.ExtList.push(recSection[key].Split(';', ' '));
                Recs[sectionName].Add(r);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The problem is very simple, and extremely strange (at least to me).
when r.ExtList.push(...) is called, I can follow the execution into the push() function with visual studio, and see that the correct strings are added to the 'Extensions' in ExtList (by hovering over it). Then, as I continue stepping through the code with visual studio, the push() function returns back to the foreach loop. And from that moment on, this Rec's ExtList no longer has any elements. They've all disappeared as soon as push() returns.

Here's the Rec struct for completeness.

```
struct Rec
{
    public string strMatch;
    ExtensionList extList;
    public ExtensionList ExtList {
        get { return extList??new ExtensionList();}
        set { extList = value; }
    }
};
```

Comment: get { return extList??new ExtensionList();} doesn't assign to private field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getter for the `ExtList` property returns the value, or if it's null, returns a new list.  You then call the getter of the object and mutate that list.  At no point in time is that list ever set to the `extList` property.  Nether the property getter, nor the code you have initializing the `Rec`, ever setting that field.

Surprisingly, this doesn't actually have anything to do with the fact that you have a mutable struct, that said, mutable structs are still evil, and you should avoid them like the plague.  Your `struct` should either be immutable, or a `class`.

Answer (score 0):

I see not reason for the `ExtensionsList` class. As presented the logic can be implemented into `Rec` directly.

```
public struct Rec
{
    public Rec(string match) : this()
    {
        Match=match;
        Extensions=new List<string>();
    }
    public string Match { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Extensions { get; private set; }
    public void Push(params string[] ext)
    {
        if(ext.Contains("ALL__"))
        {
            Extensions=new List<string>() { "*" };
            return;
        }

        if(Extensions.Intersect(ext).Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        Extensions.AddRange(ext);
    }
}
```

with similar usage:

```
    public bool readAppConfig(string appConfigPath)
    {
        Recs=new Dictionary<string, List<Rec>>()
        {
            {"Headers",    new List<Rec>()},
            {"Ignores",    new List<Rec>()},
            {"Exceptions", new List<Rec>()}
        };

        foreach(string sectionName in Recs.Keys)
        {
            var recSection=ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName) as NameValueCollection;
            foreach(string key in recSection.AllKeys)
            {
                Rec r=new Rec(key);
                r.Push(recSection[key].Split(';', ' '));
                Recs[sectionName].Add(r);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```